# EclipseLink batch update doesn't work if entity has an optimistic lock

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

[Official documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Optimizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_Batch_Writing_for_Optimization) says:

> Batch writing can improve database performance by sending groups of
>   INSERT, **UPDATE**, and DELETE statements to the database in a single
>   transaction, rather than individually

(emphasis is mine).

But if an entity has `Optimistic Locking` @Version field, then all UPDATEs are executed independently.

To prove this, here is the source code snippet `DatabaseAccessor:566`:

```
if (/* ommited */(!dbCall.hasOptimisticLock() || getPlatform().canBatchWriteWithOptimisticLocking(dbCall) ) /* ommited */) {
  // this will handle executing batched statements, or switching mechanisms if required
  getActiveBatchWritingMechanism().appendCall(session, dbCall);
  //bug 4241441: passing 1 back to avoid optimistic lock exceptions since there   
  // is no way to know if it succeeded on the DB at this point.
  return Integer.valueOf(1);
}
```

So, basically, what above snippet means, is that if Entity has an optimistic lock, then batch update will be ignored.

Is there a workaround for that? I still want to use JPA.

**UPDATE**:
It turned out that I needed to add this property to `persistence.xml` in order to enable batch update with optimistic locking:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform"/>
```

Note, that Oracle10Platform or higher could be used as a value. Lower versions don't support this feature.

Also, to enable batch writing, you have to add at least one property in your persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />
```

You can also, optionally configure batch size:

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the canBatchWriteWithOptimisticLocking() method for the platform class you are using?  This call is there so that if your driver can support returning the row counts for individual calls within the batch so that Eclipselink can throw an optimistic lock exception as required, batching can be used.

Comment: Ahh, silly me... I can't believe, I didn't check that. Yes, for Oracle it should return true. I just found it out. Sometimes, too much coding makes you not notice such little things :) Thanks, mate! Now, I should check what platform this method returns.

Comment: How did it work ? I've both the mentioned properties in my xml still I'm facing the issue! Can someone explain why please?

Comment: The solution was to use the database platform class that supports it, as not all databases give back the row counts for each statement in a batch.  You'll need to give details and write your own question if you are having problems.